# Escaping single quotes in PHP/MySQL insert not working

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to insert a string into a MySQL table using a combination of JavaScript/Ajax and PHP. After passing the desired (JavaScript) string to a PHP script using Ajax, I then attempt to insert it into a table using PHP.

The PHP script is working, however as soon as a single quote (') is encountered the insertion stops at that point. I have tried using mysql_real_escape_string(), addslashes(), htmlentities() and str_replace() in various combinations, trying this with magic quotes on and off and no matter what, the single quotes cannot be handled. I would just like to either preserve them or have them escaped properly but nothing is working for me - the string itself is from a Tweet so I'm wondering if perhaps some encoding conflict is causing this? Any advice as to how to overcome this would be greatly appreciated.

For example, to better illustrate, if I pass this string to the PHP script:

promise me you won't vote

Then after sanitizing the string with any of the methods above and inserting into the MySQL table, it will always appear like so, in the MySQL table:

promise me you won

Here is my php code:

```
include("dbconnect.php"); //connect to DB
$tweet = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tweet']); //escape the string

if($tweet != '') { //check it's not empty

$query = "insert into Tory (Content) values('$tweet')"; //insert statement

$link = mysql_query($query);
if (!$link) {
  echo "3";
  die($result);
}
echo "<p>".$tweet."</p>"; //for Ajax callback
}
```

Here is the Javascript/Ajax code:

```
$.ajax({  
    type: 'POST',  
    url: 'buildTable.php', //previous php code
    data: "tweet=" + content, //content is the tweet string as javascript var
    success: function(thetweet) {
         $(document.body).append(thetweet);
    }
});
```

EDIT: Thank you for all the comments and advice offered. A temporary solution I've used is to replace all instances of a single quote with a backslash on the client side, before passing the string to the PHP script. Then switch it back to a single quote when retrieving in either PHP or JavaScript.

Comment: What is the `$result` declared to?

Comment: Add `die("Error: " . mysql_error());` and see if there's something wrong with your query.

Comment: Bypass a lot of pain in the future and get used to declaring strings with single quotes rather than double. So in this case you could do `$query = 'insert into Tory (Content) values("'.$tweet.'")';`

Comment: Do a debug, echo `$tweet`, to make sure you are passing an escaped string. If it is escaped correctly, then the problem is in your mysql, probably your character set.

Comment: How do you *know* that the data in the table has been truncated?  How are you retrieving the data to examine it?  Perhaps the problem arises during retrieval, not during insertion.

Comment: @eggyal I'm viewing it in phpMyAdmin once the script has finished. The $tweet that is echoed at the end is also printing out the string to an HTML page in the same way it appears in the phpMyAdmin table.

Comment: Compare `$_POST['tweet']` and `$tweet` — are you sure you're correctly passing the whole string to your PHP script to begin with?  May we see the absolute minimal AJAX you're using that reproduces this behavior?

Comment: I've just tried comparing $_POST['tweet'] and $tweet and they appear the same when printed to the browser. However, as you have suggested, the string when in the javascript/client state appears normal (with single quotes etc) when I use the alert() to check it but as soon as it is passed to the PHP script and I echo it to the browser (or insert it into MySQL), the single quote truncation problem appears?

Comment: have you verified that the ajax part working correctly? If so, why have you posted it?

Comment: Yep the Ajax part is working fine - I posted it as pilcrow asked to see the minimal Ajax used.

Answer (score 3):

Insert string with single quote(`'`) or double quote(`"`) in mysql

Just Use `addslashes();` in Insertion and `stripslashes();` for fetch data.

```
$str = "Hello Friend's.. Hows you all"s.";
// Outputs: Hello Friend\'s..Hows you all\"s.
echo addslashes($str);
```

stripslashes —  Un-quote string quoted with `addslashes()`. Returns a string with backslashes stripped off. (`\'` becomes `'` and so on.) Double backslashes (`\\`) are made into a single backslash (`\`).

```
$str = "Hello Friend\'s.. Hows you all"s."; // Outputs: Hello Friend's.. Hows you all"s.
echo stripslashes($str);
```

Now we come to the point. If we insert string into database with single or double quote like this:

```
$str = “Hello Friend's.. Hows you all"s.”;
$query = “INSERT INTO tbl (description) VALUES (‘$str’)”;
```

This will occur error, but if we use `addslashes($str)` function like below and then insert into database, then no error will be occurred.

```
$str = “Hello Friend's.. Hows you all"s.”;
$desc_str = addslashes($str);
$query = “INSERT INTO tbl (description) VALUES (‘$desc_str’)”;
```

similarly we can use `stripslashes($str)` to print that table field value like this:

```
echo stripslashes($str);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily avoid the whole escaping thing if you use mysqli or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) with prepared statements. The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated anyway, so this would be the perfect opportunity to switch.

Your code would be something like (PDO, using your code):

```
$query = "insert into Tory (Content) values (:tweet)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);    // $db being your PDO object
$stmt->execute(array(':tweet' => $_POST['tweet']));    // assuming you are not verifying the tweet somewhere else
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
$link = mysql_query($query);
if (!$link) {
  echo "3";
  die($result);
}
```

With:

```
mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_errno() != 0)
  die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Remember to save `$link`: `$link = mysql_query($query)`. Standard disclaimer against discouraged `mysql_*` in favour of `PDO`/`mysqli` functions apply.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is relevant and i know it's a little late, but i've just been experiencing a similar problem when trying to create a CSV file. I could not understand why my single quotes were not being escaped.

### SOLUTION

Turns out the single quotes in my sring were smart quotes i.e. curly quotes not straight quotes.

After running the function below ([Thanks to Chris Shiflett](http://shiflett.org/blog/2005/oct/convert-smart-quotes-with-php)), my quotes were converted and my escaping issues resolved.

**Pass each field/cell value/column value to be stored through this function to convert smart characters like curly quotes and emdashs to HTML entities like straight quotes and hyphens**

```
$smart_string = "String containing smart quotes";
$safe_string = convert_smart_quotes($smart_string);

function convert_smart_quotes($string) 
{ 
    $search = array(chr(145), 
                    chr(146), 
                    chr(147), 
                    chr(148), 
                    chr(151)); 

    $replace = array("'", 
                     "'", 
                     '"', 
                     '"', 
                     '-'); 

    //return string with smart characters replaced by html safe characters
    return str_replace($search, $replace, $string); 
}
```

Like i said, not sure if this will directly help your issue, but might aid you and others in future!

Comment: Thanks - this is really helpful! I ended up doing something similar but this is more thorough!