# PHP MySQLi Prepared Statements trimming strings with "non-standard" characters?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I've run into a strange problem that I've never encountered before with prepared statements. I'm using the built in PHP MySQLi functions to insert data into the database.

The code looks like this:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pass", "test");
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `lines` (`description`) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['description']);
$stmt->execute();
```

In a textarea named 'description', the following string is entered:

> Alice likes Bob’s cat.

Note that the apostrophe is not the regular ' kind, but one that I got from copying the line out of an email (in OS X's Mail app).

When the textarea is submitted as part of a form, the value that gets stored in the field in the table is:

> Alice likes Bob

The rest is cut off. I've debugged as much as I can think of, and I know the following to be true:

1. The value of the $_POST['description'] variable is correct before it is placed in the bind_param function.
2. The database tables should be using UTF8 (I have tried collations of utf8_bin and utf8_unicode_ci but neither seem to work).
3. When I use something like phpMyAdmin to enter the same string, it works.

I'd originally thought it was an encoding problem, but point (3) seems to contradict that, so the only thing I'm left with is something wrong with the way I've set up the statement.

If anyone could shed some light it would be most helpful.

Comment: There is no proof in your question that can let you blame mysqli. As long as you fail to post a reproduceable test case that can prove a bug in mysqli prepared statements, there is point in tagging your question with these tags.

Comment: I am tagging the question as MySQLi because it involves MySQLi. I never said it was a bug with MySQLi, but there are people on this site that use MySQLi and may have encountered it before. There is no proof either that my question is in the realm of "HTML" which you keep insisting on tagging it with. This is not a HTML question.

Comment: Well, it seems an encoding issue. Check your source string's encoding and then change SET NAMES argument accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out it was encoding related as I originally suspected. The top answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910793/detect-encoding-and-make-everything-utf-8) solved the problem, however I still cannot explain why instead of only displaying the character incorrectly (or storing it incorrectly), the string was cut off at that point. If anyone has an actual answer to why that happens, it would be most appreciated, if only for academic reasons!

Comment: You should have encoding the same across 3 areas: PHP, MySQL connection and MySQL table. You can set the encoding of your connection by running SET NAMES. The smart quote is probably outside the valid character set you were using.

Answer (score -3):

You need to escape your string before you insert

```
<?php
$str = "Is your name O'reilly?";

// Outputs: Is your name O\'reilly?
echo addslashes($str);
?>
```

Example taken from PHP docs.

You may also want to consider security - inserting post data into SQL without validation is never a good idea.

Comment: How do you know he's not validating? He doesn't need to escape since he uses prepared statments

Comment: My code clearly uses prepared statements and my question title also mentions this. The "escaping" is unnecessary because of this.

Comment: Prepared statements protect aginst SQL injection - agreed - but there are many other issues out there e.g. Javascript injection that may be worth considering - just a suggestion.   Regarding the character set - it does not appear that there is a malformed character being stored - it looks like the single quote has terminated the string - as nothing appears after it.

Comment: I've already handled JavaScript injection, and that only occurs when you are outputting values from the database, not inserting them into it.

The edit to your answer is of no help either, because I am using prepared statements. If I escape the value first, the escaped string (with the backslash) will be stored as the actual value in the database, which is not what I want.

Comment: Security debate is taking us off topic - Regarding escaping - if the value is terminating the string you will need to escape / modify it - not for storage - but to ensure that PHP treats it as data rather than processing it as a token that is terminating a string.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11297223/escaping-single-quotes-in-php-mysql-insert-not-working for another example

Comment: PHP never treat any character as a delimiter. It seems you hardly understand the way PHP works.

Comment: @BillyBigPotatoes: Please go read up on Prepared Statements, and you'll understand why I'm rejecting your answer.

Comment: I agree with the point below - in terms of it being a possible mysqli bug - I am suggesting escaping will get you round the issue - clearly the prepared statement should not behave the way you are experiencing.

Comment: I don't think it's a MySQLi bug, because of point (3) in my original question. When I use phpMyAdmin to add the same string, it is inserted fine.

Comment: @BillyBigPotatoes try your own suggestions first. Then, if it ever worked, you may continue with argument.

Comment: Escaping does work - it does not explain why the issue exists in the code above! Regarding phpMyAdmin - who knows what it is doing under the covers.  It is not possible to copy and paste the PHP code verbatim via PHPMyAdmin